# How to convert date into my required format using dayjs module

Tags: javascript, cypress, dayjs, cypress-dayjs

I am reading a date from a locator through cypress the actual date is `11/04/2023`

```
cy.get("#eff-date").invoke('text').then(()=>{
const edate = dayjs(text.split(':')[1].format('DD-MMM-YYYY'))
})
```

What it is returning

```
04-Nov-2023
```

But it should be `11-Apr-2023`

Comment: In the USA, `11/04/2023` is November 4th, 2023. Does dayjs recognize locales?

Comment: There is no difference between the expected format and the actual format. Both are `DD-MMM-YYYY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to parse a non-ISO 8601 date string. According to the [dayjs docs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string):

> For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use String + Format.

The following should work.

```js
var customParseFormat = require('dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat')
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat)
...
cy.get("#eff-date")
  .invoke('text')
  .then(()=>{
    // Have to pass the custom parsing format, which is MM and not MMM
    const edate = dayjs(text.split(':')[1], 'DD-MM-YYYY');
    // To display, we have to use dayjs.format()
    console.log(edate.format('DD-MMM-YYYY');
})
```

More information on using the [String + Format (and customParseFormat) here](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/custom-parse-format)

Comment: Can confirm this works in my test.

Answer (score 4):

A better library is [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/parse). It will tell you in the test when you get the format wrong.

```js
import {parse, format} from 'date-fns'

it('tests date parsing and formatting', () => {

  const text = 'Extension date: 11/04/2023'
  const datePart = text.split(':')[1].trim()

  const myDate = parse(datePart, 'dd/MM/yyyy', new Date())
  const formatted = format(myDate, 'dd MMM yyyy')
  
  expect(formatted).to.eq('11 Apr 2023')
})
```